# Don't understand Me vs. My

Tags: grammar

Could someone please explain whether it should be "*me presenting a final thesis*" or "*my presenting a final thesis*". I've always struggled to understand when to use *me* and where to use *my* Could someone please explain the grammatical difference between the two words in this context? Thanks!

> My education culminated with *my* presenting a final thesis.

Comment: Try changing *me/my* to *John/John’s* ...

Answer (score 0):

In this example, "presenting" is a gerund, that is, a verb form ending with -ing and acting as a noun. The gerund phrase "[me/my] presenting a final thesis" also acts as a noun, as you can see by replacing it with other noun phrases:

- My education culminated with *disaster*.
- My education culminated with *a graduation ceremony*.
- My education culminated with *my favorite tune, "Pomp and Circumstance."*

So the strict rule, as explained in [this blog post](https://grammarsherpa.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/oh-me-oh-my-gerunds-and-possessive-pronouns/), is that you should use the possessive form to indicate who's performing the action. It's *your* action.

This doesn't only apply to pronouns. If someone else was giving the presentation, you might say:

- My education culminated with *the valedictorian's* presenting a final thesis.

However, as that post also points out, this rule isn't always followed; in common usage, the possessive is considered optional after a preposition. Since you have a preposition here, both forms are acceptable:

- My education culminated *with me* presenting a final thesis.
- My education culminated *with my* presenting a final thesis.